# How base64_encode byte array on php?

Tags: php, base64

How base64_encode byte array on php?

On java

```
new BASE64Encoder().encode(byte[] bytes);
```

Answer (score -3):

Use base64_encode($stringToEncode) and base64_decode($stringToDecode)

Example:

```
$string = 'Test String';
$coded = base64_encode($string);
echo $coded;
// TyByYXRvIHJldSBhIHJvcGEgZG8gcmVpIGRlIFJvbWE=

$original = base64_decode($coded);
echo $original;
// Test String
```

Comment: byte array, not string

Comment: Agree too, with C# :
byte[] playData = new byte[2 * playDataStr.Length];
return System.Convert.ToBase64String(playData)

But with php, base64_encode only takes a string